# ARKit & Vision frameworks – Detecting wall edges

Tags: augmented-reality, object-detection, arkit, coreml, apple-vision

I wonder is it theoretically possible to detect wall edges/lines (like in the picture)?

All I could achieve is detecting the vertices of rectangles that are visible to Camera Preview. But we can't consider real walls as rectangles. So, is there any advanced technique (say by training with Core ML, or something else) to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: did you fine anything ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried edge detection? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html